# Can't send_keys to input field, despite being able to find it

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, checkout

```
<mat-form-field _ngcontent-mob-c74 class="mat-form-field 
ng-tns-c19-29 mat-primary mat-form-field-type-mat-input mat-form-field-appearance-legacy mat-form-field-can-float
mat-form-field-has-label mat-form-field-hide-placeholder ng-star-inserted 
ng-touched mat-form-field-should-float ng-dirty ng-valid" data-test="name"> == $0
<div class="mat-form-field-warper">
    <div class="mat-form-field-flex">


    <div class="mat-form-field-infix">
         <input _ngcontent-mob-c74 class="mat-input-element mat-form-field-autofill-control
         cdk-text-field-autofill-monitored ng-touched ng-dirty ng-valid" formcontrolname="name" matinput 
         placeholder="Name on Card" id="mat-input-15" aria-invalid="false" aria-required="true" required> == $0
```

So basically I'm trying to input text into the above, which is a field for credit card information. I've tired using the elements:

mat-form-field
mat-form-field-wrapper
mat-form-field-flex
mat-form-field-infix
mat-input-element

I've tried the id

mat-input-15

I've tried clicking on the elements and clearing them before using send_keys. If I try to interact with any of them I get the error "element is not interactable"

There is an iframe on the page, although it has nothing in it when I inspect it using chrome so I don't think it's of any use.

Any help is appreciated, this has been bugging the entire day.

Comment: Maybe you could try executing javascript on the element to change the "value" attribute to the CC number.

Comment: document.getElementByClassName("mat-input-element").value = "some value" does actually work, not sure why it's not working for Selenium then...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon Sri's suggestion I tried to input values using javascript's .value. This worked in the chrome console so I've just used javascript in my python code, it works, although it does feel a bit janky.

```
driver.execute_script("""
     cardNumberInput = document.getElementsByClassName('mat-input-element')
     cardNumberInput[4].value = "some name"
                      """)
```

Comment: Try using explicit wait until the element is clickable. Also, use xpath to locate element.

Comment: There element is there and I can access it, I just can't write in it with Python.

Answer (score 0):

Try Explicit wait :

```
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
    WebElement el = wait.until(ec.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class=mat-form-field-infix/input")))
    el.clear()
    el = wait.until(ec.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class=mat-form-field-infix/input")))
    el.send_keys("any name")
```

Note: Please add below imports in your code:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as ec
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
```

please ignore any spelling or indentation mistake, not on my pc. Answering from phone.

Answer (score 0):

Angular material uses native inputs under the hood; you can verify that in the snippet you posted.

So a cleaner approach would be to get that native input inside the mat-input, like in the below examples:

```
element(by.css("mat-form-field input"));
element(by.css("mat-form-field.emailInput input"));
```